# Woocommerce No Price Display on Sale Item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin with a wordpress theme and after I add a 'sale price' to an item, the price no longer displays unless I go into the item details. These regular and sale prices do however display on the 'featured' and 'on sale' products displayed on the home/front page but when I go to the shop page there is no price displayed for any of the sale items. Please see jeune.co.za [work in progress]. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[style.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWPFK.png)

```
.price {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ababab;
    /* font-size: 20px; */
    color: #000;
}


  [1]: http://jeune.co.za/
```

remove the font-size on your style.css on that page, I have given you the link and it will be displayed .[image]
wp-content/themes/book-store/style.css?ver=4.3.1

Comment: This worked just perfect. Just had to reduce the font size [to 16px] and now all detail shows so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="amount">R550.00</span>
<span class="amount">R440.00</span>
here generate two span with same class name on the span when sale product
Please change class name of second price of product in span
or 
please change font size on class .price
http://www.jeune.co.za/wp-content/themes/book-store/style.css?ver=4.3.1
line no 210.
```

Comment: This worked just perfect. Just had to reduce the font size [to 16px] and now all detail shows so thank you.